# Downstream git repo with config

Tags: git

I have an open source project that I have forked, because I wish to contribute back fixes and features. So far, so good.

This project has a file, configuration.h, that is specific to me. I wish to keep it versioned. The default file is versioned by the project already. I'm aware there are better ways to manage config, but unfortunately I have to keep these files in a manner that makes them suitable to be pushed upstream.

What is the cleanest way of managing this git repo so that i have my configuration available in whichever feature/bug branch or tag I happen to be working on?

My current attempt involves keeping a config branch off master, and rebasing that around. That gets problematic very quickly. There must be a better way?

Comment: Is the file tracked in the project, or is it normally ignored? Seems odd they'd track a configuration file that changes per-user.

Answer (score 0):

There are git solutions, like the [smudge clean](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) hooks. Others hooks could do the trick, but that is not a very good solution because I think your problem is not here.

You should not have code file that are not the same for different developers. Your code base should handle different configurations stored outside the code base in configurations files that have a default template versioned `.config.template` and a custom version each one has on its machine `.config` which is not versioned (thanks to .gitignore) but is used by the code when run.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest way is to maintain two branches for your work - call them `dev` and `test`. `dev` would be all your work you do on everything except the configuration file, and would be what you use to submit changes upstream. `test` would only be your configuration file, and you can frequently merge `dev` in or rebase `test` onto the latest `dev` commit, depending on personal preference (I would prefer rebase, myself), and this branch would never be pushed upstream.

Comment: Unfortunately in this instance there are many branches analogous to dev, and you cant keep rebasing each on onto test. You would have to rebase, then unrebase all the time. Messy.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to modify your application so that tracked/untracked config are stored in different files. See https://gist.github.com/1423106 for some approaches.  Excerpted:

- Modify your app to look for foo.local.conf before foo.conf (or load foo.local.conf afterwards and have those configuration settings override foo.conf's, or read the name of the configuration file from an environmental variable).
- Track foo.sample.conf and have your compilation process copy it to foo.conf if it is not present.
- Use special smudge/clean hooks to apply your configuration changes (or take them from a special configuration file branch)
- Use [local configuration branches](http://thomasrast.ch/git/local-config.html) where you isolate your configuration changes on a special branch
- Under no circumstances should you use "assume unchanged".  It doesn't do what you want or what you think it does.  Using it will only end in tears.